# Use a reverse proxy in IIS between blazor WASM Https frontend and Localhost http .net core backend

Tags: asp.net, iis, reverse-proxy, blazor

I'm try to set up a IIS Server.
We access the blazor app on https://localhost:8081 served as a static Website
and we access the backend on http://localhost:8080 ASP.NET Core Hosted

I would like the 8081 to take the post requests made on a controller.
for this I thought about using URL REWRITE and add a reverse proxy rule (On the 8081 website)
The problem is that when my browser try to send a post request on the controller I get error 405.
This is the console:
[image]

This is my InBound Rule:
[image]

Hope you will have the god power to help me :)

Thanks

Comment: According to my test results, there is no problem with your reverse proxy rules. And from your response, it is indeed irrelevant to the rules. The allow in response shows the type of request it can receive and there is no post. Therefore, when most people encounter 405 errors, they choose the simplest and most effective method, which is to uninstall the WEBDAV module of IIS. You can try it.

Comment: Hi @BruceZhang , thanks for your answer. I tried this: https://docs.inedo.com/docs/various/iis/disabling-webdav but nothing change. I tried almost everything i found on the web... I can turn off the back end nothing changes. It seems like an "Options" request is made. I don't understand.

Comment: You turned off the backend, but still got 405, right? This shows that the problem is on the front-end server. May I know how your original request was sent?